# Basic questions on ClickOnce deployment for general user

Tags: c#

I have some clickOnce deployments folders.

Everything works under my localhost and local IIS setup.The setp.exe files can be downloaded to my local file system and installed.

I have now uploaded to the host service.

If the user downloads the setup.exe file from the website how does setup know where to find .NET files if the user does not have .NET or needs a newer version?Does it need to check the manifest files to go the the vendor's website ...I would like to ditch all the extra files generated by the publish tool.

The host service says does not like .exe files.What's the best way to deal with this?Should i simply zip the setup.exe file?

Answer (score 0):

It will check when installing for required frameworks.  Read below, link to MSDN at the bottom.

From MSDN:

> Before installing an application on a client computer, ClickOnce will examine the client to ensure that it has certain requirements specified in the application manifest. These include the following:
>
> The minimum required version of the common language runtime, which is specified as an assembly dependency in the application manifest.
>
> The minimum required version of the Windows operating system required by the application, as specified in the application manifest using the  element. (See  Element (ClickOnce Application))
>   The minimum version of any and all assemblies that must be preinstalled in the global assembly cache (GAC), as specified by assembly dependency declarations in the assembly manifest.
>   ClickOnce can detect missing prerequisites, and you can install prerequisites by using a bootstrapper. For more information, see How to: Install Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application.

[ClickOnce - Application Deployment Prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Make sure you select your version of Visual Studio/.net at the top.